# Converting VBA files to .EXE

Tags: vba, file, powerpoint, exe

I have created a huge application in VBA running powerpoint 2007 and I would like to convert it into .exe file . Any idea how could I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run a VBA form as a .exe file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340428/is-it-possible-to-run-a-vba-form-as-a-exe-file)

Comment: Its not duplicate I guess...

Comment: Well to me it looks the same (but title of the question I linked is deceptive)... Anyhow, I believe you have to convert VBA into VBS then VBS into EXE

Answer (score 0):

You can fairly easily convert VBA to VB (classic, not .NET) and from there compile to an EXE.  It won't be a standalone EXE, in that it'd require the VB runtime files, but they're installed as part of all normal Windows versions through 8 at least. Not sure of 10.

You'd start with code to launch PPT (visible or not) and get a reference to the PPT application object.  From that point, most of your code conversion would be a matter of putting what you have inside a With oPPTApplictionObject/End With context and DIMming any PPT constants in your own code.

This would allow you to "drive" PowerPoint from an EXE rather than from VBA; obviously, PowerPoint would need to be installed.  If you want to convert PPT VBA into a standalone program that doesn't require PowerPoint ... good luck.  You're then talking about rewriting PowerPoint.  May Baud have mercy upon your soul. ;-)