# Convert excel vb macro to an executable

Tags: asp.net

How to compile .vba file to .exe
Converting vba modules into an exe file.
Need to make the file executable.
Can VBA be used for programming outside

Answer (score 0):

not natvely. You could youse tools like this [Done ExXCell Compiler](http://www.soft14.com/Business_and_Finance/Spreadsheets/DoneEx_XCell_Compiler_11134_Review.html). 
I suggest you to look this topic
[Is it possible to run a VBA form as a .exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340428/is-it-possible-to-run-a-vba-form-as-a-exe-file)